# Can't access git repository of ubuntu 16.04 LTS from another OS

Tags: ssh, git

I am newbie in ubuntu and I don't have much experience in ubuntu. Now, I try to setup git server on ubuntu 16.04 LTS by learing this guide https://www.linux.com/learn/how-run-your-own-git-server.

I want to create git repository on ubuntu and I want to access that git repository from `windows 7` as remote. In my windows, I already installed `msysgit`.

But every times I try to add remote, I got fatal errors like this

```
fatal: '/Project/code_server' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I try a lot of way to solve this error more than one days but I can't solve it. I have no idea what I was wrong. So, please guide me. Here is what I've tried.

I want to setup git repository on my ubuntu personal account. So I skip adding a user `git` step from the above guide.

On my ubuntu personal account, I create git bare repository in the path `/opt/lampp/htdocs/Project/code_server` by using `git init --bare`.

(All of the following commands are made by using git bash from windows.)

After that, on my windows laptop, I create ssh key by using git bash like this:
`ssh-keygen -t rsa` without using passphrase. And copy that keys to my ubuntu laptop like this:

`$ cat /c/users/my/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh devloper@192.168.2.3 "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cat >>  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"`

After that, it shows like this

```
The authenticity of host '192.168.2.3 (192.168.2.3)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:CXpg2OJd3KCORAXHu/1zV194iEDElwtRlb8oX6i7X2Q.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

so, I said yes and it shows this warning again: `Warning: Permanently added '192.168.2.3' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.` and it ask to write password of ubuntu account and I type the password.

And I change the path to `/c/xampp/htdocs/Project/Project-0.3` and make `git init` and add all code files to version controls and commit.

And then, I try to add remote as shown in below:

```
my@Pavilion-PC MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/Project/Project-0.3 (master)
$ git remote add origin ssh://devloper@192.168.2.3/Project/code_server
```

And when I try to push, I got following error.

```
my@Pavilion-PC MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/Project/Project-0.3 (master)
$ git push origin master
developer@192.168.2.3's password:
fatal: '/Attendance/code_server' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I already set `RSAAuthentication yes` and `PubkeyAuthentication yes` and also remove comment `#` from  `AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

But the problem still exists and I can't still work with remote git repository of ubuntu from winodws. I'm very appreciate for any helps.

Comment: Where is the home directory of `devloper` user on the server?

Comment: /home/devloper/

Comment: Therefore the path is obviously wrong. How it should find `/Project/code_server` in `/home/developer/`, when it is actually in `/opt/lampp/htdocs/Project/code_server`. Something like `git remote add origin ssh://devloper@192.168.2.3:/opt/lampp/htdocs/Project/code_server` should do the job.

Comment: So, should I need to move `.ssh` key folder to `/opt/lampp/htdocs/Project/code_server`?

Comment: Nope. You should add a right path when using `git remote add`.

Comment: @Jakuje Can you please make your comment as answer because I want to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. You should add a right path when using `git remote add`:

```
git remote add origin ssh://devloper@192.168.2.3:/opt/lampp/htdocs/Project/code_se‌​rver
```